# Silverlight: Binding a Property to a DependencyProperty

Tags: silverlight, binding, dependency-properties

The XAML code:

```
<Canvas>
    <Button x:Name="btnCanvasButton" Content="Canvas Button"
            Canvas.Left="50" />
    <Button x:Name="btnCanvasButton2" Content="Canvas Button 2"
            Canvas.Top="25"
            Width="{Binding Path=Canvas.Left, ElementName=btnCanvasButton}" />
</Canvas>
```

I want to bind `btnCanvasButton2.Width` to `btnCanvasButton.Canvas.Left`, but it's not working.

I also tried `Path=Canvas.LeftProperty`, `Path=Left`, `Path=LeftProperty`, but no luck either.

Please advise.  Thx.

Peter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use parentheses to bind to an attached property.

You could try:

```
<Button x:Name="btnCanvasButton2" Content="Canvas Button 2"
        Canvas.Top="25"
        Width="{Binding Path=(Canvas.Left), ElementName=btnCanvasButton}" />
```

Comment: You are awesome.  Thank you very much.  Why cannot I find it @ MSDN.  Hmmm.